# Is everyone in Firefly fluent in Chinese or do they only know Chinese slang?

Tags: languages, firefly, serenity

Often the English-speaking characters in *Firefly* speak curses and slang in Chinese because of the mixing of American and Chinese cultures in the universe. Often audio recordings are also said in both English and Chinese.

I am wondering if there is any canon source that says that the English-speaking characters such as the Serenity crew actually know Chinese or if they simply know Chinese curses and slang.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes, they can all speak Chinese (Mandarin, in fact).**

Per this [cast/crew featurette](http://www.sciencechannel.com/tv-shows/firefly/videos/firefly-speaking-chinese.htm) with Joss Whedon:

> "The idea was that your most basic white-trash person can speak
>   Chinese. The person with no education who y'know was the last person you'd expect, speaks Chinese off the bat."

Comment: Interestingly, no one on the show ever actually spoke Chinese (Mandarin) well, so I guess the white trash descriptor was accurate.

Comment: @jamessheridan - Inara ' s pronunciation was supposedly excellent but that was more down to the actress.

Comment: And makes sense, given her position closer to high-society when compared to the others (other than Simon)

Comment: @Zibbobz - According to interviews, Simon's Chinese was absysmal. Again (out of universe) that wasn't a deliberate plan, it was just down to the actor.